# qcombobox currentindex

Tags: qt

создаю комбобокс

```
    QSqlTableModel *comboModel = model->relationModel(10);
    ui->workComboBox->setModel(comboModel);
    ui->workComboBox->setModelColumn(comboModel->fieldIndex("name"));
```

при выборе данных должен отфильтровать модель

```
 void MainWindow::on_workComboBox_currentIndexChanged(const QString &arg1)
    {

        qDebug() << "worker selected = " << arg1;
        qDebug() << clickedDay;
        model->setFilter(QString( "name = '%1' and exec_date = '%2'")
                         .arg(arg1)
                         .arg(clickedDay));
        model->select();
    }
```

При запуске программы сразу фильтрует по непонятному значению.

> worker selected =  "1" ""

Как мне поставить, чтобы по умолчанию выбрал ВСЕ поля из combobox(из базы). Или чтобы он срабатывал только когда я в комбобоксе что-то выбираю.

Comment: Попробуйте вначале заполнить combobox: `ui->workComboBox->setModel(comboModel);` и только после этого соединить его сигнал `currentIndexChanged(const QString&)` с вашим слотом `on_workComboBox_currentIndexChanged(const QString &arg1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Соединение раскрывающегося списка со слотом наверняка производится в дизайнере. Этот вывод можно сделать хотя бы по характерному наименованию слота. Соответственно связь об изменении текущего индекса в списке устанавливается до того, как этот самый список получит набор данных.

**Что происходит?**

Создаётся модель:

```
QSqlTableModel *comboModel = model->relationModel(10);
```

Модель подключается к виджету списка. Это автоматом активирует отправку сигнала об изменении индекса текущей строки:

```
ui->workComboBox->setModel(comboModel);
```

Поскольку на момент отправки сигнала свойство списка `modelColumn` по умолчанию установлено в `0`, то в подключенный слот отправляется значение, содержащееся в ячейке первой строки и первой колонки (нумерация, разумеется, производится с нуля).

Наконец устанавливается показываемая в списке колонка модели:

```
ui->workComboBox->setModelColumn(comboModel->fieldIndex("name"));
```

Здесь уже отправка сигнала об изменении текущего индекса строки не производится.

**Как победить?**

Если нет желания производить подключение сигнала к слоту после наполнения списка данными из модели, то можно поступить так.

```
QSqlTableModel *comboModel = model->relationModel(10);
ui->workComboBox->blockSignals(true);
ui->workComboBox->setModel(comboModel);
ui->workComboBox->setModelColumn(comboModel->fieldIndex("name"));
ui->workComboBox->blockSignals(false);
ui->workComboBox->setCurrentIndex(0);
```

**Что не так со слотом?**

Слот принимает строку в качестве аргумента, которая затем преобразуется в фильтр запроса к базе данных. Что произойдёт в том случае, если в таблице хранятся одинаковые строковые значения, но под разными идентификаторами?

Например, если таблица содержит имена, то два "Иван Иваныча" вовсе не такой уж редкий случай. Если таблица содержит названия населённых пунктов, то тем паче возможна ситуация полного совпадения.

Также следует помнить о том, что сравнение строк всегда медленнее, нежели чем сравнение чисел, и если таблица содержит большое количество записей, то вероятно довольно существенное проседание производительности. Впрочем, эта деталь - частный случай.

**Как же иначе?**

Можно использовать индекс текущей строки, а не её значение. Предположим, имеется таблица работников `workers`:

```
worker_id - INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT  
name      - TEXT
```

Тогда слот можно переписать на что-то иное:

```
void MainWindow::on_workComboBox_currentIndexChanged(int row) {
    QSqlTableModel *model
        = qobject_cast<QSqlTableModel*>(ui
            ->workComboBox->model());

    if(model == Q_NULLPTR) return;

    if(row >= 0) {
        // Важно понимать, что индекс строки и идентификатор -
        // это не одно и тоже, а значит из первого
        // необходимо получить второе.
        const int worker_id_col = model->fieldIndex("worker_id");
        const int name_col      = model->fieldIndex("name");

        const int worker_id
            = model->data(model->index(row,worker_id_col)).toInt();
        const QString name
            = model->data(model->index(row,name_col)).toString();

        qDebug() << "worker selected = " << name;

        model->setFilter(QString("worker_id = %1").arg(worker_id));

    } else model->setFilter(QString());

    model->select();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ага спасиб помогло. Сделал слоты и сигналы вручную а не через Designer.

```
connect(ui->ComboWorkersBox,SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(const QString&)),this,SLOT(slot_comboWorkersBox_currentIndexChanged(QString)));

void MainWindow::slot_comboWorkersBox_currentIndexChanged(const QString &arg1)
{

    qDebug() << "worker selected = " << arg1;
    if(clickedDay=="")
    {
        clickedDay = QDate::currentDate().toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
    qDebug() << clickedDay;
    model->setFilter(QString( "name = '%1' and exec_date = '%2'")
                     .arg(arg1)
                     .arg(clickedDay));
    model->select();
}
```